High performance way to read the last lines of many CSVs?
In Python I want to loop through a list of 1000+ CSV files with 100k rows and only read the last 100 or so lines of them. It takes way too much time and memory to load them into a pandas dataframe since it loads the whole file into the dataframe. What is a fast and efficient way to do this in Python?
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = "/tmp/path/to/csv/"
out = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    if np.all( df.iloc[-1] < 100):
        out.append(filename)


This might be helpful: Joran's answer on "How to jump to a particular line in a huge text file?"

Check out: Efficiently Read last 'n' rows of CSV into DataFrame

Can you predict the agerage line length?

If you have a fixed len of csv file, try to use "skiprows" in pandas read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=10**5 - 100)


But you have to take care of the headers then (if there are any), otherwise they not only get lost but are wrong.
